# Dropdown Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Dependent autocomplete drop-down, when text is typed in input it auto-completes only by first letters how to make it work with any letter, an example if i type -
"Yo" it should show "New York" in dropdown. Here is my code for that but it shows only by first letters.

```
var states = {
  'Color': ['red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', ],
  'Numbers': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
};

function match(str) {
     str = str.toLowerCase();
     clearDialog();
 for (var i = 0; i < states.color.length; i++) {

  if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(str)) {
jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');

}}}
```

Comment: `String.indexOf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf`:

```
if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(str) !== -1) {
    jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
}
```

Or a more up-to-date approach with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
    jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! How to make matching letters in dropdwon highlight or to be bold?

Comment: Ask a new question about your new problem. But I suppose something like `.replace` and reqular expression should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching out .startsWith(str) to .includes(str)?

to be more specific:

```
if (states.color[i].toLowerCase().includes(str)) {
    jQuery('.dialog').append('<div>' + states.color[i] + '</div>');
}
```